# How to run a program after reboot

Tags: gpio, python, boot

RASPBERRY PI 4

Hello there, I have this script that should shut off a power outlet when it detects a movement.

The `rpi-rf_send` code is from [this](https://github.com/milaq/rpi-rf) repo.

The question is: if the current goes away, how do I restart the script?

I tried to insert the script in `rc.local` (probably in the wrong way) but it doesn't work.

```py
import time
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import subprocess

pir = MotionSensor(pin=14,pull_up=False)

def restart_plug():
print("Starting plug...")
subprocess.run(["rpi-rf_send","8652300","-g", "3", "-p", "172"])

def stop_plug():
print("Stop plug...")
subprocess.run(["rpi-rf_send","8652292","-g", "3", "-p", "172"])
time.sleep(5)
restart_plug()

while True:
pir.wait_for_motion()
print("Waiting for motion...")

if pir.is_active:
  print("Motion detected!")
  stop_plug()
```

Comment: How exactly did you add it to rc.local.

Or in other words.

What is the **exact** command that you type in the commad line to get your script started and as which user did you start the command.

And what **exact** command did you try to add to rc.locale.

And what exactly do you mean with " it doesn't work."
Does the raspberry pi still work normally, but your code is not started. do you get any funny errors.

The reason I'm asking is, that it is difficult to help without that info

Comment: Your python script cannot work. It has wrong indents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. You should use a systemd Unit file to start your script as service. Start with the following Unit file. If it doesn't work you can adapt it to run your your script. Create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit MotionSensor.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Motion Sensor
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/full/path/to/MotionSensor.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable and monitor the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable MotionSensor.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status MotionSensor.service
```

Reboot. If it doesn't work just give a comment. Then we will see how to improve the service.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The error was in te location of the `rpi-rf_send` script. It was located in the local path of the user instead of being located in the `/usr/bin` path